# Kotlin readLine() function not working properly

Tags: kotlin

I recently made a simple user input code in kotlin and I tried to run it on intellij Idea, but it didn't work properly, when I ran the code, the "Enter text" part showed up and I can type some words, but the readLine() didn't seem to work as it doesn't continue to the last println statement.

this is the contents of my **main.kt** file

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Enter text: ")

    val stringInput = readLine()!!
    println("You entered: $stringInput")
}
```

here is the contents of my **build.gradle.kts** file

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.20"
    application
}

group = "me.rakandhiya"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnit()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClassName = "MainKt"
}
```

is there anything wrong in those 2 files?

Comment: Works fine for me in IntelliJ without gradle, so must be related to gradle.

Comment: There is no problem (as I see it) it the two files you supplied. What exactly is the problem you face? You start the application and "Enter text:" shows up. Then you add some text and press enter. What happens now?

Comment: it still runs, but it doesn't continue to the "You entered part"

Comment: I've found the solution to this, thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks to the guys that responds to the questions, it turns out that the solution to this was just changing the JRE options in the `Edit Configurations` menu, it was initially set to default option, then I change it to something else, and then I revert it back to default. And now it works perfectly!

Comment: Hey, can you tell me what you mean by "change the JRE options in the Edit Configurations menu"? Is the Edit Configurations menu specific to Intellij IDEA, or something else? I am having this exact problem right now. I even used the same code from a tutorial on the `readLine` function before I knew this was posted.

Comment: yes it is specific to Intellij IDEA