# Why does Gradle not allow me to use readLine function properly?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

**NOTE:** I have just marked this question as a duplicate.

Here is the answer: [Console application with Java and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172137/console-application-with-java-and-gradle)

---

I created a Gradle application that simply receives some input as a `String?`. When I try using the "run" task, `stringInput` evaluates to `null` automatically. I have already tested this with the Kotlin compiler in the terminal, and it works as expected.

Here is the main code below:

```
package com.s12works.readLineTest

fun main() {
    print("Enter text: ")
    val stringInput: String? = readLine()
    println("You entered: $stringInput")
}
```

The output from running this application with the `run` task:

```
**> Task :app:run**
Enter text:
You entered: null
```

How can I stop this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) `Return the line read or null if the input stream is redirected to a file and the end of file has been reached.`

Comment: Other reasons why readLine() might hit end-of-file include the user entering the end-of-file indicator (e.g. Ctrl+D on Unix/macOS), or the program running on a platform such as an online IDE which doesn't support user input.

Comment: I found something promising here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000410/kotlin-readline-function-not-working-properly. I am just confused when the answer says "change JRE options through `Edit Configurations`." Is this something specific to Intellij IDEA?

Comment: I used `java.util.Scanner` as well. It also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run` task of the application plugin is of type `JavaExec`. As you can see in the DSL reference for the JavaExec (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:standardInput) the default input stream is set to empty. To change this behavior you can add the following to your build script:

```
run {
 standardInput = System.in
}
```